Conflict between fontspec and libertinust1math
I'm trying to use fontspec with libertinust1math, but they seem to clash. Here is a minimal working code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}

$\{x \in [0,\infty)\}$

\end{document}

And here is its output:

What's going on? Can I fix this while still using these two packages?

Is it an option to use the libertinus opentype fonts?

While it's of course ok to upvote helpful answers right away, site guidelines recommend waiting at least several hours, and better still a day or two, before "accepting" any particular answer. That way, potential providers of possibly even better answers aren't needlessly discouraged from posting their solution suggestions.

@Mico in this instance egreg seems to have copied his answer from God's book of TeX support. But in general I agree, and I'll bear this in mind :)

You need the no-math option to fontspec.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}

\textit{x} $\{x \in [0,\infty)\}$

\end{document}



Thank you! I had searched for "math font" in the fontspec documentation, instead of "maths font". Meanwhile, I'm British...

@andres Will is Australian…

Just load the libertinust1math package directly; no need to load fontspec first.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\begin{document}
$\{x \in [0,\infty)\}$
\end{document}


and if the OP wanted to use fontspec to change the text font (then probably egregs answer)

@daleif - The OP didn't mention anything about a text font -- say, "Libertinus Serif". If that is, in fact, part of the program, I'd recommend running \usepackage{unicode-math}, \setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}, and \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}.
